# Will executing small-med updates on Windows 10 in a dualboot system (single SSD, partitioned) brick the Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, windows-10, 19.04

I have a dualboot system with one partition for ubuntu 19.04, the other for Windows 10 1903. I've read online that in the case of MacOS dualbooting on the same storage as Windows 10, updating Win 10 could brick the MacOS partition. Ie. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnUua6hfmjs

My question is, will running windows 10 updates have the same harmful effect on my ubuntu partition? I'm still deciding between dualbooting and running vbox (sacrifice speed for vbox, but at least its 'safer'?)

Seems that major upgrades from say, win8 to win10 have cause changes that brick the booting process, would the same happen in smaller updates such as 1903 to 1904?

Comment: Seems like it! But thats a complete full update from win8 to win10 tho. Would smaller updates like 1903 to 1904 have the same effect?

Comment: It's been 3 years since I dual booted my laptop. Single HDD, 3 partitions. I haven't experienced any kind of problem except the Windows bootloader replacing itself with GRUB. But that could be fixed by boot-repair. On a side note there won't be any 1904 on Windows.  Their major updates happen in Mar-Apr (YY03) or Sep-Oct (YY09)

Comment: Thanks for the info kulfy! So you mean that each time update occurred you'd need to execute boot-repair right? Was any data lost on Ubuntu side? I'm gonna need Ubuntu for a major enterprise project so stability is crucial to me.

Comment: No not every time. No data was lost. Windows don't know how to handle ext4 partitions unless it's formatting it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do have Ubuntu and Windows installed in dual-boot on the same drive and I just updated Windows yesterday and have not experienced any issues whatsoever in both Ubuntu and Windows partitions because of this.